# Proof that if $Y=2X+3$ then $f_Y(y)=\frac12f_X(\frac{y-3}2)$

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

I want to prove that if probability density function (PDF) of a random variable $X$ is $f_X(x)$ and another random variable $Y$ is defined as $Y=2X+3$, then the PDF of $Y$ is $f_Y(y)=\frac{1}{2} f_X(\frac{y-3}{2})$.

**My Approach**:
We Know: $P(X \leq x)= \int_{-\infty}^x f_X(x) \, dx$
similarly,$$P(Y \leq y)= \int_{-\infty}^y f_Y(y) \, dy$$
Now,$\, Y=2X+3$
$$\implies P(Y \leq y)= P((2X+3) \leq y)$$
$$=P(X \leq (\frac{y-3}{2}))$$
$$\implies P(Y \leq y)=\int_{-\infty}^{\frac{y-3}{2}} f_X(y) \, dy$$
$$\implies \int_{-\infty}^y f_Y(y) \, dy=\int_{-\infty}^{\frac{y-3}{2}} f_X(y) \, dy $$
Now how can I proceed further to find a relationship between $f_Y$ and $f_X $?

Comment: Use the change of variable $y\to2y+3$ in the very last integral.

Comment: if we put $y \to 2y +3 $ , then we will get $f_Y(y)=2 f_X(2y +3)$,now how to proceed?

Comment: No we do not get that.

Comment: In the last integral ,if we put $y \to 2y +3$ , then
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\frac{y-3}{2}} f_X(y) \, dy =\int_{-\infty}^{\frac{(2y+3)-3}{2}} f_X(2y+3) \, d(2y+3)$$
$$=\int_{-\infty}^{y} f_X(2y+3) \, 2dy$$
$$\implies \int_{-\infty}^y f_Y(y) \, dy=2\int_{-\infty}^{y} f_X(2y+3) \, dy$$
$$\implies f_Y(y)= 2f_X(2y+3)$$
so,where am I doing it wrong?

Comment: Wrong change of variable, possibly at least partly due to the horrendous practice of using the same symbol for the bound of the integral and for the variable of integration. Somehow, you are trying to get mistakes...

Comment: could you please tell in which step  I am going wrong?

Comment: You are doing the change of variable, backwards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "We know: $P(X \leq x)= \int_{-\infty}^x f_X(x) \, dx$...  "

Observe that on RHS the $x$ is fixed and variable at the same time. That is confusing notation. You should write something like:$$P(X \leq x)= \int_{-\infty}^x f_X(u) \, du$$

---

You found: $$P(Y\leq y)=\int_{-\infty}^{\frac{y-3}2}f(u)du=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\mathbf1_{\left(-\infty,\frac{y-3}2\right]}(u)f(u)du$$

(Notice that I introduce $u$ here in order to avoid the confusing notation).

Now substitute $u=\frac{v-3}2$ to get $$\cdots=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\mathbf1_{\left(-\infty,\frac{y-3}2\right]}\left(\frac{v-3}2\right)f\left(\frac{v-3}2\right)d\left(\frac{v-3}2\right)=\int^y_{-\infty}\frac12 f\left(\frac{v-3}2\right)dv$$

Comment: Sorry , i am not able to understand how you are getting "$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\mathbf1_{\left(-\infty,\frac{y-3}2\right]}(u)f(u)du$ " from  "$\int_{-\infty}^{\frac{y-3}2}f(u)du=$";could you please explain it...

Comment: If $A\subseteq\mathbb R$ is measurable then $\int_Af(u)\;du$ is nothing else but a notation for $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\mathbf1_A(u)f(u)du$. If $A=(a,b]$ then  $\int_a^bf(u)du$ is a notation for $\int_{(a,b]}f(u)du=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\mathbf1_{(a,b]}(u)f(u)du$. You can take $a=-\infty$ here.

Answer (score 2):

$$F_Y(y) = F_X\left(\frac{y-3}{2} \right)$$

Now, let's differentiate with respect to $y$ by chain rule

$$\frac{d}{dy}F_Y(y) = \frac{d}{dy}F_X\left(\frac{y-3}{2} \right)=f_X\left(\frac{y-3}{2} \right)\frac{d}{dy}\left(\frac{y-3}{2} \right)$$

that is $$f_Y(y)=\frac12f_X\left(\frac{y-3}{2} \right)$$